# Trouble following how Date and setDate are working

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me understand the following:

```
date = new Date();
date.setDate(new Date().getDate());
```

The snippet above gives a different result than the snippet below, with the difference being combining the first two lines...

```
date = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate());
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

In the first one, the `date` variable is set to the `Date` object you've created.  When logged, it's logging the string version of that full date.

In the second one, the `date` variable is set to the return value of the call to `setDate`, [which is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate#return_value):

> The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date (the `Date` object is also changed in place).

and that's what you're seeing logged there.